# Launching Eclipse 3.6 in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I'm getting a problem is launching eclipse 3.6 in Ubuntu 11.04. I'm dragging the file eclipse from folder to terminal but nothing. can someone help??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try `chown -R your_username the_folder_pathname` in Terminal.

Comment: Try copying just the eclipse folder to your home directory and run the chown command.

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
sudo chmod 766 your_username the_folder_pathname/eclipse
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a permission issue to the eclipse program.  Try putting eclipse in your home directory, or install it from the ubuntu package manager for easiest full system access.  If you must keep eclipse where you have it now (/media/Prg/Programs/eclipse) then you're going to need to give yourself access to this directory (you'll need execute permission).  Definitely easiest to put it in your home directory or install via the package manager though.

Hope this helps.

Edit: I should also mention that it is execute permission you are likely lacking here.  At least for this error it looks like execute permission on the eclipse binary itself.

Comment: Do you have a reason to not install it using the package manager?  You can click on the applications icon on the left side, type eclipse, then choose the eclipse to "install" and it should open the package manager and install it for you.